# Should I go through Munkres' book?

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, algebraic-topology, soft-question

I am now a first year graduate student and I am interested in algebraic topology for many reasons. I took an undergraduate course in metric topology, but I didn't take one in general topology. However, I have a more than sufficient background in abstract algebra, I will very soon take a course in differential geometry (I already took one as an undergraduate, but it was of an elementary flavor - now I am going to study manifolds, etc.) and I have (intensely) studied topics like measure theory, so maybe I am "too mature" to go through a textbook like Munkres'?

I think I have two choices: go deep into topology and study from a textbook like Munkres', or start head-on with an introductory algebraic topology textbook which is tolerant to people who never seriously studied general topology (example: Lee's *Introduction to Topological Manifolds*). My main two concerns are: the lack of enough time and the possibility of wasting some.

What do you think should be done? Do you recommend an alternative to the above two plans?

I also don't have advisers or anyone in my uni to talk to about my situation, so I would really appreciate your advice as I don't know where else I can find one.

Comment: Really, Hatcher's online notes on general topology are probably more than suited for your needs - they're quite short, and cover the basic essentials. When you need to know what a paracompact space is and why anyone cares, you can look that up. Similarly with function space topologies or other stuff you might otherwise find in Munkres. Big fan of Banach manifolds, by the way, you guys are great.

Comment: @MikeMiller thank you for your recommendation. Is this the one you are talking about? http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/Top/Topdownloads.html

Comment: I've voted to close this question as seeking personal advice; you're free to email me if you care to. I think advice-related questions are often better received on Reddit, though I'm not a user.

Comment: I have one caveat with the idea of going straight to Hatcher. Many students have trouble with quotient topology constructions, and Hatcher assumes that his readers completely understand those constructions. Munkres has a good chapter on the quotient topology which anyone, whatever level of maturity, will appreciate. Generally speaking, Munkres will cover many general topology topics with a level of rigor which is expected in more advanced textbooks.

Comment: Which Munkres book are you referring to? There are two: https://www.amazon.com/Topology-2nd-James-Munkres/dp/0131816292 https://www.amazon.com/Elements-Algebraic-Topology-James-Munkres/dp/0201627280

Comment: @yoyostein I am referring to "Topology".

Comment: @LeeMosher Do you mean Hatcher's algebraic topology book? I agree that Hatcher's general topology notes are brief on quotient spaces, but they cover the requisite material, and I've had success with students who needed to catch up on topology going first through those (though I've never tried to teach a course with those notes amounting to the content of the first half or anything like that).

Comment: @BanachManifold If you find the first too basic you may wish to jump straight to Munkres Algebraic Topology. Or even Rotman Algebraic Topology, which is written from an Algebraist perspective so may be suitable for your case.